# Timechart with distinct_count per day

Tags: splunk

I have a query which shows me the number of hosts for which a given event is logged more than three times within a single day:

```
index=desktopevents "target" 
| stats count by host | dedup host 
| where count > 3 | stats dc(host)
```

What I can't figure out is how to use this with `timechart` so I can get the distinct count *per day* over some period of time. The naive timechart outputs cumulative `dc` values, not per day (and obviously it lacks my more-than-three clause):

```
index=desktopevents "target" 
| timechart span=1d dc(host)
```

I thought this might work but the chart is blank:

```
index=desktopevents "target" 
| stats count by host | dedup host 
| where count > 3 | timechart span=1d dc(host)
```

Comment: Just a note: `| stats count by host | dedup host ` does not make sense - you already have `by host`, so de-duping is done.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks, I thought so, a co-worker insisted it was necessary to optimize the where clause...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `bin` to group by 1 day

Preparing test data:

```
| gentimes start=07/23/2021 increment=1h 
| eval _time=starttime 
| eval host="host"+tostring(random()%18)
```

Now the full query with aggregation and filtering:

```
| gentimes start=07/23/2021 increment=1h 
| eval _time=starttime 
| eval host="host"+tostring(random()%18) 
| bin span=1d _time 
| stats count by _time host 
| where count > 3 
| timechart count
```

Comment: You can also use the `date_day` field instead of running `bin` (ref: https://antipaucity.com/2020/08/18/how-to-timechart-possibly-better-than-timechart-in-splunk/#.YSeqxMYpBAc)

Comment: @warren - I wanted to preserve the ability to use `timechart` explicitly, and for that you need to keep `_time`.  Otherwise I would've used `stats` in both cases.

Comment: fair enough - though `timechart` is an expensive operation, and you can achieve the same results using `stats` :)

Comment: @warren - Yes, I agree.

Comment: Management likes `timechart` :)